# how to achive drag and drop functionality extjs 4.0.2a

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member I am using ext js4.0.2a and **has achieved a task to show desktop with icons on it**, when the application runs.

Now I want to add the drag and drop functionality to my desktop icons, but don't know how to achieve it.

I am using ext js 4.0.2a with MVC architechture so, is there any way I can achieve it. I had seen some examples, but they all based on version lower than ext js-4.

**Please guide me how can I achieve this task of adding drag and drop functionality to my desktop using ext js 4.0.2a**

Answer (score 0):

There is a Drag and Drop guide http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/drag_and_drop
and several examples for 4.0.7 which is compatible with your version, plus a few bug fixes.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/dd/dnd_grid_to_grid.html

Hope this info helps.

Comment: thanks.. is this drag_and_drop works with the ** desktop icons also **

Comment: To be honest I have not tried that desktop example. I don't see why they wouldn't work - everything is one Ext component or another :)

Comment: not still not able to get this work to be done. I want my desktop icon to arranged as per the user wish. Just like in windows we arrange our desktop icons.you can also have a look to [link]http://code.google.com/p/extdim/w/list, but it's in extjs-3 version without mvc